# Casting JSpinner's date value to integer

Tags: java, swing, date, jspinner

I have 2 methods for getting a DateModel for a JSpinner and another method to set the JSpinner's editor to show the editor's format to 00:00. The input value it expects is time in "HH:mm"

```
public class JSpinnerUtilities {
    public static SpinnerDateModel getADateModel(){
        Date myDate = new Date();
        SpinnerDateModel mySpinnerDateModel = new SpinnerDateModel(myDate,null,null,Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        return mySpinnerDateModel;
    }

    public static JSpinner.DateEditor getEditorInTimeFormat(JSpinner aJSpinner){
        Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        Date myDate = myCalendar.getTime();

        JSpinner.DateEditor myDateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(aJSpinner, "HH:mm");
        aJSpinner.setValue(myDate);

        return myDateEditor;
    }
}
```

Then I use it to set any JSpinner objects' model and editor.

```
startTimeJSpinner.setModel(JSpinnerUtilities.getADateModel());
startTimeJSpinner.setEditor(JSpinnerUtilities.getEditorInTimeFormat(startTimeJSpinner));
endTimeJSpinner.setModel(JSpinnerUtilities.getADateModel());
endTimeJSpinner.setEditor(JSpinnerUtilities.getEditorInTimeFormat(endTimeJSpinner));
```

The problem is, I don't know how I can convert it to an `int` before inserting to the database.

```
Object objectStart = startTimeJSpinner.getValue();
Object objectEnd = endTimeJSpinner.getValue();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Start: "+objectStart+"\n"+"End: "+objectEnd);
```

I get this.

[image]

I searched online and checked related questions then I tried to cast it to Number and int but was unsuccessful.

I need to be able to get **230** and **330** for instance, **2:30** and **3:30** because my field in database is an `Int`

Is there any possible way to achieve the conversion to an Int?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you fix your database and use a Time rather than an int? Anyway, what have you tried? If I tell you that the current time is 2016, August 21, 10:09, howdo you transform that into 1009? You extract the hour from the date, then you extract the minutes, then you combine them (by concatenating, or by multiplying the hour by 100 and adding the minutes), right? So, why don't you do that?

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks for the tip. I actually tried getting it as Object then I tried to Convert it to a Number but the Number type can't be converted to an int. I followed you suggestion and achieved the int by concatenating and parsing to Integer after I extracted the HOUR and MINUTE. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to JB Nizet for the suggestion.

Here's what I did.

```
Date startDate = (Date) startTimeJSpinner.getValue();
        Date endDate = (Date) endTimeJSpinner.getValue();
        Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCalendar.setTime(startDate);
        int myStartHours = myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int myStartMins = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int myStartTime = Integer.parseInt(myStartHours+""+myStartMins);

        myCalendar.setTime(endDate);
        int myEndHours = myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int myEndMins = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int myEndTime = Integer.parseInt(myEndHours+""+myEndMins);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Start: "+myStartTime+"\n"+"End: "+myEndTime);
```